# How can I display a picture on a control in PyQt4?

Tags: python, image, pyqt

I'd like to display a picture on my form using PyQt4.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        #The setGeometry method is used to position the control.
        #Order: X, Y position - Width, Height of control.
        self.resize(500,350)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sergio's QT Application.")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('menuScreenFolderShadow.png'))

        self.setToolTip('<i>Welcome</i> to the <b>first</b> app ever!')
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', 12))

        self.txtFirstName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
        self.txtFirstName.setGeometry(35, 35, 150, 20)

        self.txtLastName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
        self.txtLastName.setGeometry(35, 60, 150, 20)

        self.pictureA = QtGui.QIcon("C:\Users\Sergio.Tapia\Downloads\Palm.png")
        self.pictureA.setGeometry(128,128, 200, 200)

        btnSubmit = QtGui.QPushButton('Say hello.', self)
        btnSubmit.setGeometry(340, 250, 150, 35)
        self.connect(btnSubmit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clicked)

        btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit Application', self)
        btnQuit.setGeometry(340, 300, 150, 35)

        self.connect(btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
                    QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))

    def clicked(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Just dropped by to say hi!", "Welcome to this tutorial %s %s!" % (
            self.txtFirstName.text(), self.txtLastName.text()))

    def center(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size =  self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width()-size.width())/2, (screen.height()-size.height())/2)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainForm = myWindow()
mainForm.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It says that:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Sergio.Tapia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PyQTTests\src\pyqttests.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       mainForm = myWindow()   File "C:\Users\Sergio.Tapia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PyQTTests\src\pyqttests.py",
>   line 25, in **init**
>       self.pictureA.setGeometry(128,128, 200, 200) AttributeError: 'QIcon'
>   object has no attribute 'setGeometry'

If I remove that setGeometry line, the application launches but the picture isn't displayed anywhere. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, for example using the `QPixmap` class. Once again, I encourage you to take a look at the examples available with PyQt. For example, `examples\animation\appchooser\`, or `examples\widgets\icons\`